# How to not close string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a bit of code that is in hundreds of my pages and I need to take it off. the problem is that it has `<?php ?>` tags, `"` and `'`.

What I was thinking to do was turn the bit of code in a string and use str_replace() once I fopened the file, but the ' and " are closing the string, making it impossible for me to do.

For example, it's something like this:

```
<?php $x = "test"; echo '1234;' ?>< ?php $y = 'testing' ?>
```

Is there a way to do stop it from closing strings? Or do you suggest any other solution?

Comment: Try to use \ before the character

Comment: I thought about that but then str_replace() wouldn't find it since it's different than the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is not recursively embeddable or executable. Just because your files contain PHP code doesn't mean that php code magically special - inside the file, it's just text, like any OTHER text. You can search/replace as you want

```
$code = file_get_contents('somefile.php');
$fixed = str_replace('<?php blah blah blah ?>', '', $code);
file_put_contents('somefile.php', $fixed);
```

And note that that is literal PHP code inside the str_replace call - like I said, PHP is not recursively embeddable/executable. That's not really PHP code. It's a plain PHP string that happens to contain characters that end up LOOKING like php code.

e.g.

```
<?php
echo '<?php echo "foo"; ?>';
```

doesn't output just "foo". You get the literal characters `'`, `<`, `?`, `p`, etc... as the output. That internal `echo foo` business is not PHP code in this context. It's a PHP string that contains characters that would be PHP code if it wasn't inside the `'` quotes.

Comment: I understand that, but what I mean is: if I try to put it in a string it would be something like `$string = ' <?php $x = 'test'; echo "1234"; ?> ';`. The ' would nullify itself.

Comment: Escape your string markers with a backslash. `$string = '<?php $x=\'test\'; echo "1234"; ?>';`

Comment: Then you have to escape the internal quotes, exactly as you would with any OTHER text that contains the same quotes you've delimited the string with: `$name = 'Miles O\'Brien';`

Comment: I thought about that but then str_replace() wouldn't find it since it's different than the original.

Comment: no. because the escapes are consumed by the PHP parser. the in-memory string will not contain them. that's the whole point of escaping. it's like wrapping paper on a birthday present. You don't want little Timmy (PHP) to see the contents of the string (the internal quotes) as something special (terminating the string), so you escape (wrapping paper) the quotes. Once you've handed the gift (escaped string) over to Timmy, the wrapping paper gets removed and anything special inside the string is no longer relevant - it's loaded into memory as it should be -without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch all the PHP tags in a file, you could loop through them, then run a `preg_replace` to pattern match the tags and remove them.

A quick example for regex could be http://regexr.com/3cu2t